# how to read a complex type array<string> on impala or hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet, impala

I try to read a complex type on hive

```
dog.owners (array<string>)
```

with the following query

```
select dog_id, concat_ws(',',collect_set(owners)) as owners 
from dog 
group by dog_id
```

but i receive the following error

> `Argument 2 of function CONCAT_WS must be "string or array<string>", but "array<array<string>>" was found.`

Looks like there is a data type mismatch. I tried to create the column owners as an `array<array<string>>` but i still get the same error.
Is there a way to read that column on hive or impala?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? sample data and the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: You don't need `collect_set`

Answer (score 1):

```
select dog_id, do.* from dog, dog.owners as do
```